# Executing Java Main class in Maven pom.xml profile

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am able to start my application using the maven command line using the following command:

```
mvn -f test-framework/pom.xml exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.application.app" -Dexec.classpathScope="test" -Dexec.args="/META-INF/spring/application-context.xml" -Denv=stubbed -Dsys=app -Dspring.profiles.active=app
```

I would like to modify the pom.xml of my project so that I can automatically start the application during a test job using Jenkins. 
I would like to know how I can translate the above Maven command into a Maven profile. I have done the following but the application does not start:

```
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-app</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>mvn</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>${sut.path}/app/test-framework</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>exec:java</argument>
                                <argument>"-Dexec.mainClass=com.application.app"</argument>
                                <argument>"-Dexec.classpathScope=test"</argument>
                                <argument>"-Dexec.args=/META-INF/spring/application-context.xml"</argument>
                                <argument>-Denv=stubbed</argument>
                                <argument>-Dsys=app</argument>
                                <argument>-Dspring.profiles.active=pdc</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

Anyone can help how I can make the command into pom.xml profile?

Comment: Wouldn't using the `exec:java` goal be more convenient than passing `exec:java` as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `<start-class>` property?

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.stackoverflow.MyClass</start-class>
    </properties>
```